# Buffer overflow - terminator canaries

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am reading an article on buffer overflow protection [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Terminator_canaries).

For terminator canaries, I follow the part that if a terminator like a zero is used for a canary, the attacker would have a terminator in the overflow, which will cause the overflow to stop, preventing overflow of return address.

But the next sentence is not clear:

```
The undesirable result is that the canary is known. Even with the protection, 
an attacker could potentially overwrite the canary with its known value, and 
control information with mismatched values, thus passing the canary check code, 
this latter being executed soon before the specific processor's 
return-from-call instruction.
```

I am not able to follow this argument.

Does it imply that terminator canary can be bypassed in any way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic idea of a terminator canary is that when an attacker attempts a buffer overflow, they're forced to over-write the canary value.  The program can then detect that the canary has changed value and take appropriate actions.

The value `0` is somewhat special in programming: many languages use it as an end-of-text marker.  If an attacker is trying to overflow a text buffer, the use of a `0` as a terminator canary means the attack will fail: in order to keep the canary from changing, they need to include a `0` in the oversized input in a location that will cause almost all of the excess input to be ignored.

This has a problem, though: if the input is handled as binary data rather than as text, the fact that the canary has a known, fixed value means the attacker can simply over-write the canary with itself, producing an undetectable overflow.

**Edit:** code examples

```
/* This reads a length-tagged packet of up to 16 bytes length from an input stream.
 *
 * Note that since the programmer forgot to check the length of the input,
 * a packet of more than 20 bytes (give or take alignment) will overflow onto
 * sensitive parts of the stack.  If bytes 17 through 20 of the outsized packet
 * are 0s, this overflow won't be detected.
 */
size_t readPacket(char *stream)
{
    size_t length;
    char packet[16];
    uint32_t canary = 0;

    length = (size_t)(*stream++);
    memcpy(packet, stream, length);
    processPacket(packet, length);

    if(canary != 0)
        exit(0);
    return length;
}


/* This reads a username from an input stream.
 * 
 * Note that since the programmer used strcpy() rather than strlcpy(), a
 * string of more than 20 bytes (give or take alignment) will overflow onto
 * sensitive parts of the stack.  However, since strcpy() stops copying once
 * it encounters a byte with the value 0, in order for overflow to reach a 
 * sensitive part of the stack, it must change the value of the canary.  If
 * this happens, exit() is called and the changed stack is never used.
 */
size_t readName(char *stream)
{
    char userName[16];
    uint32_t canary = 0;

    strcpy(userName, stream);
    processUserName(userName);

    if(canary != 0)
        exit(0);
    return strlen(userName);
}
```

In a real-life example, the canaries and canary-checking code may be inserted automatically by the compiler rather than manually by the programmer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the meaning of "if the input is handled as binary data than as text" .. ? What copy mechanism does this include like strcpy, memcpy .. ?

Comment: Text is normally handled as "a series of non-`0` bytes followed by the value `0`".  Binary data is handled as "a sequence of bytes of a certain length", or for input, it's sometimes "a sequence of bytes extending to the end of the file".  Binary data doesn't have a special value indicating the end of the data, while text does.

Comment: So in a C program, would kind of copying mechanism should a developer use .. to handle input as binary data .. that could still lead to buffer overflow ? I am aware of strcpy & memcpy, but not sure which one of these or any other you are indicating. Thanks.

Comment: If you could provide some sample C code, that would really helpful to understand your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Jake consider `memcpy` or `memset`, or simply writing 'char' values at each offset of a region one by one, rather than `str*` functions which would only modify the memory region until a 0 is encountered.

Comment: @SteveDL considering *memcpy*, it has a third argument indicating number of bytes to be copied .. won't a programmer use the right number of bytes to copied .. thereby preventing buffer overflow altogether .. I think because if a wrong value for number of bytes is used .. then the program itself does buffer overflow .. even when not attacked .. please help me clarify. thanks

Comment: @SteveDL what do you think of Mark's answer .. the part "input is handled as binary data rather than as text" .. does it refer to memcpy / memset ?

Comment: @Jake I think this is what Mark means yes. With memcpy you might actually have an attack that changes the buffer size to be copied (any invalid write of 1 byte or more at a chosen location should suffice), and then be allowed to copy more of your arbitrary data than the program expected/had previously checked.

Comment: @Mark:should the canary (set to zero) in your sample code be above or below the declaration of buffer ?

Comment: @Jake, that's a tricky question to answer.  The compiler will *usually* lay out memory in the order the variables are declared, in which case `canary` will come after `buffer` in memory and be overwritten by an overflow, but it's not guaranteed.  That's one of the reasons the canaries should be inserted by the compiler rather than the programmer.

Comment: Cannot comment because my account is new. But in @Mark's code, the canary needs to be defined before the buffer. Stack overflow occurs from lower to higher addresses that is towards the stack segment where return address is present.

Comment: @user487478, a compiler is free to re-arrange the ordering of local variables in a function, which is why a real canary needs to be inserted by the compiler.  In my testing, `clang` ordered them "canary, packet, length" (the reverse of the order they're written in), while `gcc` ordered the variables "canary, length, packet" (a totally different order).  Additionally, `gcc` did not include any padding, while `clang` padded "packet" out to 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The redhat [Security Technologies: Stack Smashing Protection (StackGuard)](https://access.redhat.com/blogs/766093/posts/3548631) blog has a good explanation under the Terminator canaries section

> Most buffer overflow attacks are based on certain string operations which end at string terminators. A terminator canary contains NULL(0x00), CR (0x0d), LF (0x0a), and EOF (0xff), four characters that should terminate most string operations, rendering the overflow attempt harmless. This prevents attacks using strcpy() and other methods that return upon copying a null character while the undesirable result is that the canary is known.

> This type of protection can be bypassed by an attacker overwriting the canary with its known values and the return address with specially-crafted value resulting in a code execution. This can be when non-string functions are used to copy buffers and both the buffer contents and the length of the buffer are attacker controlled.